# how can I connect many-to-many tables in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, sequelize.js

`I have a data base in my localhost and I want to show the "tickets" of an "passenger". I'm working with nodejs, mysql2 and sequelize. The structure of the sql is:

```
CREATE TABLE pasajero (
    pasaporte integer PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre character varying(20),
    pais character varying(20)
);
CREATE TABLE viaje (
    codigo integer PRIMARY KEY,
    codvuelo character varying(20) REFERENCES vuelo(codigo),
    costo integer,
    fecha date,
    piloto1 integer REFERENCES piloto(id),
    piloto2 integer REFERENCES piloto(id)
);

CREATE TABLE ticket (
    idpasajero integer REFERENCES pasajero(pasaporte),
    codviaje integer REFERENCES viaje(codigo),
    PRIMARY KEY (idpasajero, codviaje)
);
```

For the "ticket" table, "idpasajero" and "codviaje" remained as primary keys, following this model they were defined as follows:

```
const PasajeroModel = db.define(
    "pasajeros",
    {
      pasaporte: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
      nombre: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      pais: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
    }
  );
const ViajeModel = db.define(
  "viajes",
  {
    codigo: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
    codvuelo: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    costo: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
    fecha: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
    piloto1: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
    piloto2: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);
const TicketModel = db.define(
  "tickets",
  {
    idpasajero: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    codviaje: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);
PasajeroModel.belongsToMany(ViajeModel, { through: TicketModel ,foreignKey:"pasaporte"});
ViajeModel.belongsToMany(PasajeroModel, { through: TicketModel ,foreignKey:"codigo"});
```

Mi actual controlador es este:

```
export const misTickets = async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const tickets = await PasajeroModel.findAll({
            where:{
                pasaporte: req.params.pasaporte
            },
            include:[{
                model: ViajeModel
            }]
        })
        res.json(tickets)
    }
    catch(err){
        res.json({message: err.message})
    }
}
```

I tried to test the code in Thunder CLient and it gave me this message:
{
"message": "Unknown column 'viajes->tickets.pasajeroPasaporte' in 'field list'"
}`

Answer (score 0):

In `foreignKey` options of `belongsToMany` associations you should indicate a field from a junction table (Ticket in your case):

```
PasajeroModel.belongsToMany(ViajeModel, { through: TicketModel ,foreignKey:"idpasajero"});
ViajeModel.belongsToMany(PasajeroModel, { through: TicketModel ,foreignKey:"codviaje"});
```

And `Ticket` model should have its own primary key.